# Set global variables between scripts in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developping a chrome extension.

In my website i've a:

> windows.open("website_number_1.html");

Then my manifest.json is:

```
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["website_number_1.html"],
        "js": ["script1.js"]

      },
```

The thing is, i want to launch script1.js only if the website_number_1.html is being opened from the window.open(); . So i was thinking about declaring a global variable just after the window.open like:

> global var launch = "yes";

and then in script1.js:

```
if launch == "yes"{
    my_script
}
else{
  //do nothing
}
```

Thanks very much in advance. Cheers

Comment: Variables are per-frame meaning another window doesn't share the context.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
"tabs"
],
```

In Script1.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = tab.url;
    var host = link.hostname;

    var valid_url = "valid url page";

    if(host == valid_url){
        //Code
    }else{
        //This is element in HTML of course you can make other function 
        $("#host").html("This Page is not correct ");
    }

})
```

});

I think that this is good :)

PS: 
sorry for my bad English